# How to setup VIM for php development?

Tags: vim, php, autocomplete, vim-plugins

I have been trying a lot (but not smartly) to figure out setting up VIM, ctags, omnicomple for PHP development.

On Googling I found [this file](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3171). But have no clue how to use it.

*What have I done until now?*
Here it is:

1. I am on Fedora 17 64-bit OS
2. Logged in as root Found my VIM version
   to be `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled May  8 2012
   15:05:51)`
3. Followed the install details as here http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3171

> install details
>       Place in $HOME/.vim/autoload/phpcomplete.vim and enable the php ftplugin

What else I am missing?
How do I start using omnicomplete. (this is the first time I am using omnicomplete)

*Why didn't I try IDE's?*

I have a single core machine running LAMP stack. Didn't wanted to slow down everything and hence sticking to command line environment.

Comment: Not directly related, but it may improve VIM... You can install a different color scheme, one that is more (or less) subtle, depending on what you need or like. http://cocopon.me/app/vim-color-gallery/ and http://www.vimninjas.com/2012/08/26/10-vim-color-schemes-you-need-to-own/

Comment: Hello Ashwin, There is the link related to your question for the best VIM customization. There are many usefulness of VIM for Php development. http://bit.ly/2Hvhe5f

Answer (score 1):

Vim already does PHP completion. The file in question is only an improvement over the default function. Anyway, to make it really useful you'll need a `tags` file that you generate with exuberant-ctags.

Read `:help ins-completion`, specifically the part on "omni completion", and `:help ft-php-omni`.

And you missed an *important* step: google "vim php ide" (without the quotes).

Answer (score 0):

Look at my VIM config: 
https://github.com/exu/vim-dotfiles

- I'm using PIV (PHP Integration For VIM) + CTags (exuberant-ctags)

For tag generation I use command below:

```
ctags-exuberant -f tags \
    -h ".php" -R \
    --PHP-kinds=cfiv \
    --totals=yes \
    --tag-relative=yes \
    --PHP-kinds=cfiv \
    --regex-PHP='/(abstract)?\s+class\s+([^ ]+)/\2/c/' \
    --regex-PHP='/interface\s+([^ ]+)/\1/i/' \
    --exclude="*.js" \
    --exclude=".svn" \
    --exclude=".git"
```

UltiSnips as snippets for code generation (most powerfull snippets for VIM)

Look at my .vimrc, there are some PHP related things too.

Answer (score 0):

to generate tags for ctags, you'll need [**exuberant-ctags**](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/).

Pseudo steps to follow:

1) install exuberant-ctags on machine
2) issue ctags command in command line (what @jacek wrote)
3) in vim, normal mode, type:

```
:set tags=<tags location>
```

4) You can now use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> like commands to view function definitions.

TagBar can be used to show function & variable names of local buffers: [**Github tagbar**](https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar)

To save typing step (4) every time vim starts, I have the following in my vimrc to do php specific setups:

```
autocmd FileType php call SetPHPOptions()
function! SetPHPOptions()
    setlocal shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 expandtab makeprg=php-xdebug\ %
    :call tagbar#autoopen(0)
    :set tags=~/.vim/php.tags
endfunction
```